# Knockout.js add variable to code

Tags: javascript, variables, knockout.js

I'm new to KO.js and have had some help with another problem that's now solved. I have added a row to the database that's called "group_id" in the "users" table.

Now the code I will be linking to bellow already has some variables in the Javascript that points to username, userid and so on.
I want to add the "group_id" as a variable in the Javascript just as the user_name already is.
Check the link bellow and CTRL + F "this.group_id" I've added it but can't get it to work, any ideas and tips for me?

URL: http://pastebin.com/nwdPebHX

Thanks!

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: I checked the console and this is what I got:                                                                [20:41:18.661] Error: Unable to parse bindings.
Message: ReferenceError: group_id is not defined;
Bindings value: click: $root.show_user_profile, css: {admin : group_id == 1} @ http://finch.byethost8.com/scripts/ko.js:57

Comment: Yup, look in the console and see if you get any errors.

Comment: [20:41:18.661] Error: Unable to parse bindings.
Message: ReferenceError: group_id is not defined;
Bindings value: click: $root.show_user_profile, css: {admin : group_id == 1} @ http://finch.byethost8.com/scripts/ko.js:57

Comment: These bindings don't appear in the code you pasted. Are you sure you pasted the correct code? Do a view source on the page and paste the html from there.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/nwdPebHX check this link for the entire code of the page. CTRL + F "group_id" and you'll find it all.

Comment: Nope, still not there. Can you look in the html, or expose the page to the outside so that we can look at it?

Comment: http://finch.byethost8.com/?page=chat there's the page, enter a Username and NO password and you're in! once logged in some things will be buggy because of this group_id not being correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after a long discussion on chat with the OP, we managed to fix the problem. It involved changing php code on the server too, besides the js.

Comment: Thanks for all help! I can't uprate it because I don't have 15 reputation... But as soon as I have I will uprate this, I'm very greatfull!